# Centering images within a flexible container

Tags: css, image, percentage, centering

Been playing around for a while now with trying to get this to work so I have set up a CodePen and hope you guys can help:

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lvwha)

I need the `height` and `width` of `.container` to be specified with percentages rather than static pixel widths to fit my design and keep it all fluid and responsive.

In the pen remove the pixel dimensions set on `.container` and you'll see what happens.

Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modern browsers you can use absolute positioning and `transform` to position the image

```
.container
  width: 50% 
  height: 50%

  background-color: #ebebeb
  position: relative

img
  position: absolute
  left: 50%
  top: 50%
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/KnHod

Comment: keep in mind you will have to add vendor prefixes where required.. i have only posted the standard syntax for the `transform`

Comment: Perfect! I did try with negative left and top margins but it uses the percentage dimensions of the parent so transforms works on the dimensions of the element itself which is good to hear. I am using Compass so have prefixes in place. I do need IE8 support so will add that last in javascript. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps bro. Check it, I did it with an `background-image`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaptKnee/eb7u9/1/)

---

Have fun >:D

Comment: Oh alright, then you can add the image to your div and locate it (: